# Classic ASP / VBSCRIPT 12 Hour Format from FormatDateTime()

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I sure would appreciate some help. I was able to hack away at getting my time formatted as 8:53 AM from a value such as this 7/31/2020 08:53:20 AM with the following.

```
replace(replace(formatdatetime(formatdatetime(myRS("dateTime"),4)),":00 AM"," AM"),":00 PM"," PM")
```

But I would think there is a more efficient approach no?

Comment: Your code is incomplete what represent `myRS` ??

Comment: If your method works and gets you what you need, you'd actually only need 1 set of `replace(xxx, ":00 ", " ")` so that you don't have to bother with checking both AM and PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set speech = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
Speech.speak "Here's one way it sets the locale to New Zealand which is 12 hours  - it does NOT set time zone"
SetLocale("en-nz")
speech.speak now()
speech.speak "Here's another way" 'if locale is 12 hours it does nothing
Do
    If Hour(Now) < 12 then 
        Var = Hour(Now) & " AM"
    else
        Var = Hour(Now) - 12 & " PM" 
    End If

    speech.Speak Var &  " and " & Minute(Now) & " minutes and " & Second(Now) & " seconds"
    wscript.sleep 5
Loop
```

As you can see it speaks the comments.

Comment: This worked for me, but one thing. If the time is the 1st hour, I got an 00 for  Hour (Now) and it did not put out 12:01 AM, but rather 0:01 AM

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBScript"%>
<%
    
    ' The actual LCID.
    
    Response.LCID = 2057
    Response.CodePage = 65001
    
    
    Function AM_PM_Time(TheTime, ZeroPad)
        
        Dim actual_LCID, time_formatted, time_split_1, time_split_2
        
        ' Make sure the the date or time being passed is valid.
        
        If NOT isDate(TheTime) Then Exit Function
                        
        ' Make a note of the actual LCID.
        
        actual_LCID = Response.LCID
        
        ' Change the LCID to 1033 so time is formatted as 00:00:00 AM/PM.
        ' If your LCID is already 1033 you can delete the LCID code.
        
        Response.LCID = 1033
        
        ' Format the current date / time. 
        
        time_formatted = FormatDateTime(TheTime,3)
        
        ' Split the time stamp.
        
        time_split_1 = Split(time_formatted,":")
        
        ' Split the AM / PM.
        
        time_split_2 = Split(time_formatted," ")
        
        ' Revert the LCID back to its original value.
        
        Response.LCID = actual_LCID
        
        ' [Optional]
        ' Zero-pad the first number of the timestamp, for example: "07:45 PM" rather than "7:45 PM"
        
        If ZeroPad Then
        
            If Len(time_split_1(0)) = 1 Then time_split_1(0) = cStr("0" & time_split_1(0))
        
        End If
        
        ' Output the newly formatted time.
        
        AM_PM_Time = time_split_1(0) & ":" & time_split_1(1) & " " & time_split_2(1)
            
    End Function
    
    Response.Write AM_PM_Time(Now(),True) & "<br>"
    Response.Write AM_PM_Time("2020-08-17 09:00:00",False) & "<br>"
    Response.Write AM_PM_Time("14:55:00",True)
    
%>
```

Example output:

> 07:45 PM
> 9:00 AM
> 02:55 PM